# ItemIndex of DataLIst in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know whether i should be asking this question here or not but let me ask.

What is ItemIndex actually in Datalist?
What is its purpose?

I have this code.What is the purpose if ItemIndex here.

```
   foreach( DataListItem dli in mydatalist.Items )
    {
       bind_dlcmt(dli.ItemIndex);

    }


public void bind_dlcmt(int itm_indx)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment, sq.con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DataList dl = (DataList)mydatalist.Items[itm_indx].FindControl("dl_cmt");
    dl.DataSource = sdr;
    dl.DataBind();
}
```

***Note:Please dont provide me any msdn links..if possible explain yourself.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataList` object contains a collection of `DataListItem` objects. We can get this collection, like below:

```
mydatalist.Items
```

Each item of them has an index, which we can get it using this property, `ItemIndex`. If we know the index of an item in this collection, we can get the corresponding item from the collection. It is like the index of an array.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, The item index is telling you where in the collection that specific item is. Indexes usually start at 0 and go up from there.

```
Items[itm_indx]
```

is just telling it which item you are specifically referring to.

Hope that wasn't too vague